# How can I install install linksys WUSB54GS V2 to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have install Ubuntu 11.04 and I tried to just plug in my adapter and see if it would work. It doesn't so I went to the Ubuntu forums. It said I had to install Ndiswrapper but I have to have internet which I do not have! I can't move the computer at all and it is driving me crazy. If anyone can help me that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Please run lsusb and edit your question to add your cards exact details.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually seeral differenet ways that you can get this card to work... but unless you want to do this by "sneaker-net" (i.e. using an external drive between your computers for it), plug it into an Ethernet cable. Then, from there, open a terminal to do everything below, pressing return after each command typed:

- Type dmesg | grep usb
- Look for your card in the output, then continue by ensuring the package lists are updated...
- Type sudo apt-get update
- Type sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree prism2-usb-firmware-installer linux-wlan-ng
- Type rmmod p54usb isl3887usb
- Type modprobe p54usb isl3887usb
- Now, do a ping, or package update to see if this worked; it should with Mint 13+, or Ubuntu 12+, and a wusb54g v2 card. Now, if it's a v4 instead of a v2, I suggest to give up with that one on amd64, because it doesn't work well on it (the device fails to wakeup according to the logs).

If it doesn't, there's a post where someone else has the needed file that you can find at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1470224

I hope this helps you and/or others that have this card.

Comment: Can this work on Ubuntu 10.04? its less complicated